# Why is this JSON is not parsing?

Tags: javascript, json

I have some test data I receive from a server:

```
var data = [ '{"i":5,"t":3,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
                                    '{"i":6,"t":1,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
                                    '{"i":11,"t":3,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
                                    '{"i":14,"t":2,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
                                    '{"i":16,"t":1,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
                                    '{"i":23,"t":1,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
                                    '{"i":26,"t":2,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
                                    '{"i":27,"t":2,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
                                    '{"i":30,"t":2,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
                                    '{"i":31,"t":3,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
                                    '{"i":4,"t":3,"f":2,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
                                    '{"i":10,"t":3,"f":2,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
                                    '{"i":12,"t":3,"f":1,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
                                    '{"i":13,"t":3,"f":1,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
                                    '{"i":15,"t":3,"f":2,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
                                    '{"i":17,"t":3,"f":2,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
                                    '{"i":18,"t":3,"f":2,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
                                    '{"i":20,"t":3,"f":1,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}' ];
```

It gets generated from the server from this:

```
json_response.push(JSON.stringify({i : [some value], t:  [some value], f:  [some value], m:  [some value], h:  [some value], c :  [some value]}));
});
```

I know want to access some of this data. So try to access the first element:

```
console.log(data[0].i); //gives undefined
```

I then tried to parse the data:

```
var json_parse = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data[0].i); //gives undefined
```

but this gives the error that there is a `syntaxError: Unexpected token` ,

I can't see where there would be an expected comma anywhere?

I would like to be able to access the values in this json array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var json_parse = JSON.parse(data[0]);
console.log(json_parse.i);
```

And switch your server to generate the response like so:

```
json_response.push({i : [some value], t:  [some value], f:  [some value], m:  [some value], h:  [some value], c :  [some value]});
```

Comment: It works! Is there a way I could though not parse every single json object? A change to the server or client code? I ask because some of some arrays will contain a lot of objects and if I will need to parse each one it I have performance concerns. The parsing occurs on the client side which can be some old mobile phones

Comment: To add to the reason for switching the response generation, the data right now is an array of strings. Notice that each of your entries is surrounded by a single quotation, you want to remove that. The error "i" is undefined is because each entry isn't an object but a string (i.e. "mystring".i is undefined).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass an array to JSON.parse. What you have is an array of JSON strings. A simple solution is to parse each item in the array;

```js
var data = ['{"i":5,"t":3,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
    '{"i":6,"t":1,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
    '{"i":11,"t":3,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
    '{"i":14,"t":2,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
    '{"i":16,"t":1,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
    '{"i":23,"t":1,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
    '{"i":26,"t":2,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
    '{"i":27,"t":2,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
    '{"i":30,"t":2,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
    '{"i":31,"t":3,"f":3,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
    '{"i":4,"t":3,"f":2,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
    '{"i":10,"t":3,"f":2,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
    '{"i":12,"t":3,"f":1,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
    '{"i":13,"t":3,"f":1,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
    '{"i":15,"t":3,"f":2,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
    '{"i":17,"t":3,"f":2,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
    '{"i":18,"t":3,"f":2,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}',
    '{"i":20,"t":3,"f":1,"m":null,"h":0,"c":"2016-02-28T22:30:56.000Z"}'
  ];

  // For each element in array
  var data2 = data.map(jsonString => JSON.parse(jsonString));
  // Single parse
  var data3 = JSON.parse('[' + data.join(',') + ']');
  console.log(data2[0].i); // 5
  console.log(data3[0].i); // 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Point to note,

1) your `data` in the question is an array `[ ]` and it contains multiple strings, ie: your entire stringified multiple objects.

So in that case `data[0]` is valid and not `data[0].i`

2) this line `var json_parse = JSON.parse(data);` is wrong. You are trying to parse an variable that is already an array. You can parse only a JSON, In this case its not a Json its an Array..

So this would be right. `var json_parse = JSON.parse(data[0]);`

Since you said you will have multiple objects and you cannot parse each and every index in data, you can try the below logic.

```
var parsedData = data.map(eachIndex=> JSON.parse(eachIndex));
console.log(parsedData[0].i);
```